# Node.js GraphicsMagic: check installation & functionality

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am working with the `Node.js` module `gm` ([Github](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm))  for `GraphicsMagic` ([Link](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html)).

How can I determine whether the required `GraphicsMagic` software for the `gm` module **is installed & fully functional** on the current node.js machine or not? (I want to check this on the initialization process of my server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call the command line tool and check the output.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("gm", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // Validate the output with one of the parameters.
});
```